# Recursive function in C to print 1 to n to 1

Tags: c, recursion

For example: for n = 5 the result should be: 123454321.
I've managed to do so with 2 functions which will get called one after the other: the first for printing 1 to n, and the second for printing n-1 to 1:

```
void oneToN(int num)
{
    if (num == 1)
        printf("%d",num);
    else
    {
        oneToN(num-1);
        printf("%d",num);
    }
}
void NToOne(int num)
{
    if(num >= 2)
    {
        printf("%d", num - 1);
        NToOne(num - 1);
    }

}
```

I was wondering if it's possible with only one recursive function

Comment: Note that in current version your `oneToN` cannot be tail-call-optimised as you read some parameters after the recursive call, meaning your stack grows linearly with `num`. The same applies for the single-recursive-function answers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here is a general plan on how to deal with recursive problems:

- Look for the trivial case when you do not need a recursive invocation
- Imagine that you have a function working, and all you need to do is coming up with just one additional step of the function

Here, you would discover a simple pattern: if you have a function that prints 2345432, all you need to do is to print 1s around it. Hence, you need to supply two numbers - the `from` and the `to`. When the numbers are the same, you print one copy, and you are done. Otherwise, you print the `from`, do the recursive call, and print the `from` again. Done!

Answer (score 1):

123454321 is 1 + 2345432 + 1
2345432 is 2 + 34543 + 2
34543 is 3 + 454 + 3
etc

See the pattern?

The function should print the current number twice, with a recursive call to handle the higher numbers in between.

```c
void f(int n, int i) {
    if (i == n) {
       printf("%d", i);
    } else {
       printf("%d", i);
       f(n, i + 1);
       printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

This can be simplified by factoring out the leading (or trailing) `printf`.

```c
void f(int n, int i) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (i < n) {
       f(n, i + 1);
       printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

---

I would still use a second (non-recursive) function in practice.

```c
void _f(int n, int i) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (i < n) {
       _f(n, i + 1);
       printf("%d", i);
    }
}

void f(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
       _f(n, 1);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling such a function with `NToOne(1, 4)` should be enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
NToOne(int num, int max)
{
    printf("%d", num);
    if(num < max)
        NToOne(num + 1, max);
    else if (num == max)
        printf("%d", num+1);
    printf("%d", num);
}

void
print_1_to_n_to_1(int n)
{
    NToOne(1, n-1);
}

void
main(void)
{
    print_1_to_n_to_1(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do this by using single recursive function.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
//Recursive Function
void func(int n,int i){
    if(i<=n){
       cout<<i;
       func(n,++i);
    }
    if(i<=n)
      cout<<i-1;
 }

int main(){
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   func(n,1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler and easier to read if you remove the `++i`. and replace the second `if` with `if(i<n) cout<<i;` With or without that change, it would be better if the second `if` was in the first.

Comment: Yeah we can do with this approach also just to make the things clear
void func(int n,int i){
     if(i<=n){
        cout<<i;
        func(n,i+1);
    }
    if(i<n)
    cout<<i;
}

Answer (score -2):

We can easily get that pattern with only one recursive function called 'work'
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUzJN.jpg)

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.